# A block on a rough horizontal surface. Condition for the block to move along the surface

Tags: physics

> It is inclined to the vertical at an angle $\theta$. The coefficient of friction is $u$? The block can be pushed along the surface only if_______
>   [image]

Clearly, the total normal force on the block will be 
$$N=Mg+Mg\cos\theta$$Then friction would be 
$$f=uMg(1+\cos\theta)$$
So $$F\sin\theta \ge f$$
$$Mg\sin\theta \ge uMg(1+\cos\theta)$$
$$\sin\theta \ge u(1+\cos\theta)$$
I can’t go further, the answer is $$\tan \theta /2 \ge u$$

Comment: That looks good. I think giving the condition as you have is enough. Another way to go is to solve for the critical angle which is $2\arctan(u)$. To check if your result looks reasonable: note that if $u=0$ then the block will move as long as $\theta > 0$ which is correct (no friction so any force in the $x$ direction will do). If $\theta = \pi$ then it will not move no matter how small the friction is (also reasonable as this time the force points stright up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}.$$ Now, you will be able to push the block if: $$Mg\sin\theta \ge u(Mg+Mg\cos\theta) \Rightarrow \sin\theta \ge u(1+\cos\theta) \Rightarrow \frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}=\tan\frac{\theta}{2} \ge u$$